# How to send arrays to email using angular and firestore

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, sendgrid

I'm trying to send array data from firestore database using sendgrid.

I have tried using the documentation to no luck.

```
export const newOrder = functions.firestore
    .document("checkout/{checkoutId}/products/{productId}")
    .onCreate(async (change, context) => {
        // Read booking document
        const postSnap = await db
            .collection("checkout/{checkoutId}/products")
            .doc(context.params.productId)
            .get();

        const booking = postSnap.data() || {};


        //Email
        const msg = {
            to: "wilmutsami@gmail.com",
            from: "test@example.com",
            templateId: TEMPLATE_ID,
            dynamic_template_data: {
                subject: "Hey there, thank you for your order!",
                name: [booking.name],
                amount: [booking.amount]
            }
        };

        //Send it
        return sgMail.send(msg);
    });
```

Comment: {{#each products}}
    {{name}}: {{price}}
{{/each}}   //This is the html code

Comment: I verified the [documentation](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/sending-email/how-to-send-an-email-with-dynamic-transactional-templates/) and it seems that it's not possible send a data array but I will investigate further

Comment: Your example seems incomplete. What array are you trying to send? "{{#each products}}" I dont see any products property in your example

Comment: I think that is not implemented send arrays using the dynamic_template_data:  as [per](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/856)